# Can I use pthread mutexes in the destructor function for thread-specific data?

Tags: pthreads, mutex, destructor, ssl

I'm allocating my pthread thread-specific data from a fixed-size global pool that's controlled by a mutex. (The code in question is not permitted to allocate memory dynamically; all the memory it's allowed to use is provided by the caller as a single buffer. pthreads might allocate memory, I couldn't say, but this doesn't mean that my code is allowed to.)

This is easy to handle when creating the data, because the function can check the result of `pthread_getspecific`: if it returns `NULL`, the global pool's mutex can be taken there and then, the pool entry acquired, and the value set using `pthread_setspecific`.

When the thread is destroyed, the destructor function (as per `pthread_key_create`) is called, but the pthreads manual is a bit vague about any restrictions that might be in place.

(I can't impose any requirements on the thread code, such as needing it to call a destructor manually before it exits. So, I could leave the data allocated, and maybe treat the pool as some kind of cache, reusing entries on an LRU basis once it becomes full -- and this is probably the approach I'd take on Windows when using the native API -- but it would be neatest to have the per-thread data correctly freed when each thread is destroyed.)

Can I just take the mutex in the destructor? There's no problem with thread destruction being delayed a bit, should some other thread have the mutex taken at that point. But is this guaranteed to work? My worry is that the thread may "no longer exist" at that point. I use quotes, because of course it certainly exists if it's still running code! -- but will it exist enough to permit a mutex to be acquired? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pthread_key_create()` rationale](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_key_create.html#tag_03_534_08_01) seems to justify doing whatever you want from a destructor, provided you keep signal handlers from calling `pthread_exit()`:

> There is no notion of a destructor-safe function. If an application does not call pthread_exit() from a signal handler, or if it blocks any signal whose handler may call pthread_exit() while calling async-unsafe functions, all functions may be safely called from destructors.

Do note, however, that this section is informative, not normative.

The thread's existence or non-existence will most likely not affect the mutex in the least, unless the mutex is error-checking. Even then, the kernel is still scheduling whatever thread your destructor is being run on, so there should definitely be enough thread to go around.

Comment: Excellent. That's plenty enough for my purposes. (I actually think I'd seen that page on my searches but dismissed it because it seemed to be just the man page, but in HTML! - more fool me for skimming - thank you for the precise pointer.)